# What is quote_preview table used for in Magento 2

Tags: database, magento2.2, quote

I was checking the quote tables in Database and stumbled upon **quote_preview** table, anyone have idea what it is used for ?

Comment: What is your magento version?

Comment: Magento2.2.6 CE @SohelRana

Comment: Check your thirdparty module. This is not default magento table.

Comment: @SohelRana its part of module-checkout-staging\Setup\InstallSchema.php

Comment: module-checkout-staging is not CE, this is EE

Comment: I will write tomorrow regarding this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `quote_preview` table is a part of Magento Content Staging functionality. As a user should not be able to place an order during preview mode, all quotes are stored in `quote_preview` table (payment infrastructure has additional validation for the preview mode) and this table is cleared by cron.

The more details about this functionality you can the [official documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/mrg/ee/CheckoutStaging.html).